# One list item in Two columns - issue with long string of text causing gap, CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one list item and I want to have the list spreading into Two columns.

I have got this working however when there is a long string of text in one of the li's it causes a gap on the opposite column

I have a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q7ryE/

How can I avoid this when there are long strings of text, so everything fits in a nice list view in two columns with no gap / spaces?

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list removedArea">
        <li><span>more text here</span></li>
        <li><span>more text here</span></li>
        <li><span>more text here</span></li>

    <!-- Long string causes gap pushing the li down on opposite site -->

       <li><span class="fl">this is a very long name which will overlap and cause a gap, i need to reduce this gap when there is a long string of text</span>
       </li>

       <li><span>more text here</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour given your html, I think you need to have two lists side by side if you want to avoid this.

Comment: Can this not be done altering the html and css, rather than jQuery?

Comment: Basically u want to make the li's height same ..???

Answer (score 1):

You can use overflow in a proper way so tat the spaces will be avoided..

**Modified CSS**

```
 .list.removedArea li {
    display: block;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    border-right: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    color: #222;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x: hidden; // added
    overflow-y: scroll; // added
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ryE/3/)